# R shiny, load data based on input

Tags: r, shiny

I have data for each day in server side and want to load data based on date input

On server side, I have this:

```
 dateInput("date","Enter a date:",value = "2014-01-13"))
```

On UI side,

```
library(shiny)
library(googleVis)
library(rpart.plot)

load("data_2014_01_13_new.RData")  #seg and fit are data in this file
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$values <- renderGvis({
      gvisTable(seg[seg$rate >= input$test[1] & seg$rate <= input$test[2],])
    })
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
     prp(fit,extra=T)
    })
})
```

I want to put load into server function and can load different data as date changes. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read these pages in the tutorial:

- http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#scoping
- http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#reactivity

You can put the `load` call inside of the `shinyServer` function in another `reactive` so that you can reference the dataset dynamically, and each session can have different data loaded simultaneously.

So add a function like this into your `shinyServer` function (note that you'll probably need to massage the format of the date input string to make it compatible with how your files are named).

```
dataset <- reactive({
  filename <- paste0("data_", input$date, ".Rdata")
  load(filename)
})
```

then you can reference `dataset()` in other places in `server.R` to get the appropriate value for this user's dataset.

Comment: Hi Jeff, Thanks for you answer! I am trying this. I tried to load seg and fit separately and worked. While how can I select different data inside dataset? I tried dataset()$seg. It gave me an error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors.

Comment: This actually doesn't work, as `load` returns the *name* of the loaded object, not the object itself (thus leading to Yoki's error). You could change it to `get(load(filename))`

Comment: Suggestion: Edit the accepted answer to incorporate @David Robinson's comment. I spent hours trying to figure out why this wasn't working before seeing this.